# When converting Date entry in pandas, how to ignore empty values?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have an excel with some date entries as below.

```
   Case Number    Status    Date/Time Opened  Date/Time Resolved  Date/Time Closed
             1    Closed    2/1/2017 7:15 AM   2/1/2017 10:44 AM  2/21/2017 11:50 AM 
             2  Assigned    2/2/2017 2:09 PM                       
             3  Resolved   2/8/2017 10:32 AM   9/11/2017 8:49 PM   
             4    Closed   8/27/2018 6:00 AM  10/15/2018 9:10 AM  10/15/2018 9:10 AM 
             5  Resolved  12/26/2018 3:25 PM   2/11/2019 9:08 AM
```

Initially I'm converting them from the above pattern to `$year-$mm-$dd`.

```
   Case Number    Status Date/Time Opened Date/Time Resolved Date/Time Closed
             1    Closed       2017-02-01         2017-02-01       2017-02-21
             2  Assigned       2017-02-02                NaN              NaN
             3  Resolved       2017-02-08         2017-09-11              NaN
             4    Closed       2018-08-27         2018-10-15       2018-10-15
             5  Resolved       2018-12-26         2019-02-11              NaN
```

With these converted dates, I'm trying extract month and year in the format `$mon $year`.

I'm using following code to extract month and year.

```py
df['Month Opened'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date/Time Opened"]).map(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[x.month] + " " + str(x.year))
```

When I have applied this formula with 'Date/Time Opened', I can see that it works as below.

```
   Case Number    Status Date/Time Opened Date/Time Resolved Date/Time Closed  Month Opened  
             1    Closed       2017-02-01         2017-02-01       2017-02-21      Feb 2017 
             2  Assigned       2017-02-02                NaN              NaN      Feb 2017
             3  Resolved       2017-02-08         2017-09-11              NaN      Feb 2017
             4    Closed       2018-08-27         2018-10-15       2018-10-15      Aug 2018
             5  Resolved       2018-12-26         2019-02-11              NaN      Dec 2018
```

Here's my complete code - http://tpcg.io/X5S8Pe

```py
import pandas as pd
import calendar

CaseDetails = {
        'Case Number':          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        'Status':               ['Closed',              'Assigned',         'Resolved',          'Closed',              'Resolved'],
        'Date/Time Opened':     ['2/1/2017 7:15 AM',    '2/2/2017 2:09 PM', '2/8/2017 10:32 AM', '8/27/2018 6:00 AM',   '12/26/2018 3:25 PM'],
        'Date/Time Resolved':   ['2/1/2017 10:44 AM',   '',                 '9/11/2017 8:49 PM', '10/15/2018 9:10 AM',  '2/11/2019 9:08 AM'],
        'Date/Time Closed':     ['2/21/2017 11:50 AM',  '',                 '',                  '10/15/2018 9:10 AM',  '']
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(CaseDetails,columns= ['Case Number', 'Status', 'Date/Time Opened', 'Date/Time Resolved', 'Date/Time Closed'])

df['Date/Time Opened'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time Opened']).dt.date
df['Date/Time Resolved'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time Resolved']).dt.date
df['Date/Time Closed'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time Closed']).dt.date

print (df)

df['Month Opened'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date/Time Opened"]).map(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[x.month] + " " + str(x.year))
df['Month Closed'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date/Time Closed"]).map(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[x.month] + " " + str(x.year))

print (df)
```

As expected, my code converted entries under 'Date/Time Opened' to the desired format. When tried converting other 2 dates columns, I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 21, in <module>
    df['Month Closed'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date/Time Closed"]).map(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[x.month] + " " + str(x.year))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2158, in map
    new_values = map_f(values, arg)
  File "pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx", line 1569, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer (pandas/_libs/lib.c:66440)
  File "main.py", line 21, in <lambda>
    df['Month Closed'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date/Time Closed"]).map(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[x.month] + " " + str(x.year))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/calendar.py", line 56, in __getitem__
    funcs = self._months[i]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float
```

I wanted to know is there a way to covert the columns with empty values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) - it working nice with missing values:

```
df['Date/Time Opened'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time Opened']).dt.strftime('%b %Y')
df['Date/Time Resolved'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time Resolved']).dt.strftime('%b %Y')
df['Date/Time Closed'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time Closed']).dt.strftime('%b %Y')
```

Alternative is use `apply` with list of columns:

```
cols = ['Date/Time Opened','Date/Time Resolved','Date/Time Closed']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).dt.strftime('%b %Y'))

print (df)
   Case Number    Status Date/Time Opened Date/Time Resolved Date/Time Closed
0            1    Closed         Feb 2017           Feb 2017         Feb 2017
1            2  Assigned         Feb 2017                NaT              NaT
2            3  Resolved         Feb 2017           Sep 2017              NaT
3            4    Closed         Aug 2018           Oct 2018         Oct 2018
4            5  Resolved         Dec 2018           Feb 2019              NaT
```

In your solution is possible use nice trick `np.nan != np.nan`, so in your function is added `if-else` statement:

```
f = lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[x.month] + " " + str(x.year) if x == x else np.nan
df['Date/Time Opened'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time Opened']).map(f)
df['Date/Time Resolved'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time Resolved']).map(f)
df['Date/Time Closed'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time Closed']).map(f)

print (df)

   Case Number    Status Date/Time Opened Date/Time Resolved Date/Time Closed
0            1    Closed         Feb 2017           Feb 2017         Feb 2017
1            2  Assigned         Feb 2017                NaN              NaN
2            3  Resolved         Feb 2017           Sep 2017              NaN
3            4    Closed         Aug 2018           Oct 2018         Oct 2018
4            5  Resolved         Dec 2018           Feb 2019              NaN
```

Or alternative:

```
f = lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[x.month] + " " + str(x.year) if x == x else np.nan
cols = ['Date/Time Opened','Date/Time Resolved','Date/Time Closed']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).map(f))
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. Save lots of my time!

Comment: Which method do you, suggest is more efficient?

Comment: @SudhashriSHebbar - I guess first, but the best test in large data.